# Show that G is Abelian and Determine its order

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G=\langle(123)(4567), (89)(10\ 11), (8\ 11)(9\ 10)\rangle ≤ S(11).$

(a) Show that G is abelian and determine its order.
[I have a brief idea on this one, by using abelian property of commutativity, you can multiply the elements. However i don't know how to calculate the order of G. Is it 3? Since there are 3 elements in G]

(b) Give a complete list (without duplications) of all isomorphism classes of abelian groups having order |G|.

[For this i will need my answer from A to correctly answer i believe]

(c) Determine the isomorphism class of G.

[These below two i also have little idea]

Thanks, help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Have you learned about finding the order of an element like $(1\ 2\ 3)(4\ 5\ 6\ 7)$? It's definitely more than $3$. I do suspect you've got the right idea for the Abelian part.

Comment: i know how to find the order of an element! However how do i find the order of the group G in this case?

Comment: Well, for any element $g$ of a group $G$, then the subgroup $\langle g \rangle$ generated by $g$ is a subgroup of $G$, right? So $G$ must have at least as many elements as $\langle g \rangle$. My point was just that $3$ is certainly too small.

Comment: Okay, so if i find that the order of the permutations in G are 12, 2 and 2 in order. This would mean that the order of G would have to be 12?

Comment: I think there's some confusion about what "order" means here. The order of $G$ is just the number of elements in $G$. (The connection with the definition of the order of an element, is: the order of $g\in G$ is the size of the subgroup of $G$ generated by $g$.) So if $G$ had only three elements, then yes, the order of $G$ would be 3. But $G$ has lots more than three elements! $G$ isn't the *set* $\{(123)(4567), (89)(10\ 11), (8\ 11)(9\ 10)\}$, it's the *group generated* by that set! So, for instance, it also contains things like $[(8\ 9)(10\ 11)][(8\ 11)(9\ 10)]=(8\ 10)(9\ 11)$.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to part (a) for the most part:

From the [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1445976/show-that-g-is-abelian-and-determine-its-order?noredirect=1#comment2945393_1445976)

> Okay, so if i find that the order of the permutations in $G$ are $12, 2$ and $2$ in order. This would mean that the order of $G$ would have to be 12?

Calling your generating permutations $\alpha, \beta,$ and $\gamma$ and assuming they commute (they do), then it's not *quite* so easy. It *will* turn out that $\alpha \beta \gamma$ has order $12$. But there are, as I mentioned, at least as many elements in $G$ as there are in $\langle \alpha \rangle = \{\alpha^k : k = 0, 1, \ldots, 11\}$ which has $12$ elements. But, wouldn't $ \alpha^k,\ \alpha^k \beta,\ \alpha^k \gamma$, and $\alpha^k \beta \gamma$ all be distinct elements of $G$, for each $k = 0, 1, \ldots, 11$?

For part (a), you should convince yourself that this is true (note that $\beta$ and $\gamma$ alone would generate a group isomorphic to the Klein four group, the non-cyclic abelian group of order $4$). Not only are these all distinct group elements, they're *all the* distinct group elements! (Again, make sure you're able to justify this). So your group has order $12 \cdot 2 \cdot 2$.

When you convince yourself that this is true, you should be able to express your group as a direct sum (or 'product', whatever we call it) of cyclic groups. Recall, for part (b), that *all* finite Abelian groups can be [classified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian_group#Classification) as such a direct sum, using only groups of prime-power order as summands. This will allow you to place you group on this list, if you understand how to arrive at the order in part (a).